# Missing data when getting data from SQL using coordinates with this (Google) given algorithm

Tags: algorithm, maps, coordinates

```
SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('.$lat.') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * 
                cos( radians( longitude ) - 
                radians('.$lng.') ) + 
                sin( radians('.$lat.') ) * 
                sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20
```

This query has not failed me so far except for now.

I've tried playing with my database for a while and I found out that some data are not displayed that has a certain coordinate. All data I have on my database are displayed except for these two:

**Coordinates that CANNOT be displayed using the algorithm:**

```
Longitude: -80.155897 Latitude: 25.889437

Longitude: -80.175042 Latitude: 26.362099
```

**Coordinates that CAN be displayed using the algorithm:**

```
Longitude: -81.727737 Latitude: 30.164858

Longitude: -84.379269 Latitude: 33.786884

Longitude: -84.366086 Latitude: 33.823498

Longitude: -104.956408 Latitude: 39.727102
```

There's still a lot of data in my database that are working correctly except those two above. I can assure you that the coordinates are the problem because I did a bunch of testing. I'd love to debug this myself but I am very inexperienced with that certain algorithm, I am hoping that someone experienced in using it could help me out. I got that algorithm from a google map's developer page. I'll post it here when I find it. Lots of thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if tags are correct. May be sql tag ?